# How to include mod_ssl into httpd on rhel5.4

Tags: rhel5, apache-2.2, mod-ssl

I'm trying to get apache running over https with mod_ssl on a rhel 5.4 x64 machine.

I don't have mod_ssl.so in the modules directory, nor can i find any ssl type output from httpd -M or httpd -l.

Yet if i run ldd against it i can see relevant shared library dependencies.

```
ldd /usr/sbin/httpd
  <blah>
  libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00002b69cf11a000)
  libssl.so.6 => /lib64/libssl.so.6 (0x00002b69d1348000)
  libcrypto.so.6 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.6 (0x00002b69d1592000)
```

Do i need configure mod_ssl somehow to make it work as yum can't seem to find the relevent module to install itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html and http://www.modssl.org/example/

Comment: Okay, so the ldd output is a red herring and i actually need to go get the source and compile from that?

Comment: yes if it apache web server, you will need to configure web server for modssl